# next character prediction with GRU gives different results each time

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, lstm, tf.keras

I am trying to predicts a evolution of sentiments in a dialouge. To that end, I have used BERT to get the sentiments. Then for each call, I have encoded sentiments as P for Positive, E for Negative and N for Neutral. Thinking that this is just a next character prediction problem, I have used this   https://www.tensorflow.org/text/tutorials/text_generation tutorial verbatim to train it on my own data. The problem is that it gives different results each time I run inference.

| call_index | sentiments |
| --- | --- |
| 6081bdea52c838000aaa53d3 | PNNNNPNPNPPENNNNNEPNNE |
| 6081c27bde933a000a4384b0 | PENNNNNEENNPNPEPNPPNNNNNNNNNNN |
| 6081c54dd12abf000ab3c6f5 | NNPNNNPNNNPPNNN |
| 6081c666d7a1f7001cecce98 | NNNNNPP |
| 6081d8576eb5530043e3401f | NNNNPNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNPPNNNNNNNNNENNNNNNENNNN |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the simplest non-trivial approaches to text generation is to do what is implemented in the tutorial at the `###`-highlighted line:

```
@tf.function
  def generate_one_step(self, inputs, states=None):
    input_chars = tf.strings.unicode_split(inputs, 'UTF-8')
    input_ids = self.ids_from_chars(input_chars).to_tensor()
    predicted_logits, states = self.model(inputs=input_ids, states=states,
                                          return_state=True)
    predicted_logits = predicted_logits[:, -1, :]
    predicted_logits = predicted_logits/self.temperature
    predicted_logits = predicted_logits + self.prediction_mask

    ### THE FOLLOWING LINE IS IMPORTANT ###
    predicted_ids = tf.random.categorical(predicted_logits, num_samples=1)

    predicted_ids = tf.squeeze(predicted_ids, axis=-1)
    predicted_chars = self.chars_from_ids(predicted_ids)
    return predicted_chars, states
```

You were probably alerted because you expected the generation to be deterministic, which is true for the naive approach: always return the most probable character/word/token/etc., but this is not how language works at all. If you're interested in the details, go watch the Stanford NLP course (it is freely viewable on YouTube), otherwise, well, there you go, there is randomness in the algorithm.